# how to calculate string length dynamically in js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

following the code to calculate number of msgs where the user still writing the message

```
<script>
 if (($('#Msg').val().length) <= 70) {
     $('#smscount').text(Math.ceil(($('#Msg').val().length) / 70));
 }
 else 
{
     $('#smscount').text(Math.ceil(($('#Msg').val().length) / 67));
}
</script>
```

but it keeps dividing by 70 , i need to change divider to 67 when message length more than 70 char , i mean the code in else statement is not reachable in my case , why?

Comment: How are you calling this code? As it's shown, its only ever called once when the page is first rendered.

Comment: That code won't run at all. The parentheses in the `if` statement is unbalanced, so you will get a syntax error.

Comment: @StephenMuecke , i'm calling it here : <span id="smscount" style="font-weight:bold;">0</span>

Comment: @Guffa thanks compiler , the code if is working and its okay, now why it didn't reach else?

Comment: No, that's just the element where you display the message. The script as you have shown runs only once when the page is loaded, so if the message length is initially less than 70, then its divided by 70. I'm guessing you probably want to handle the `.keyup()` event of the textbox so the value is updated as you type (but not sure what you really want)

Comment: well that make sense , could u suggest some code with .keyup() , so i tick it for you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to handle the `keyup` event of he textbox so that the value is updated as you type, then the script should be

```
var count = $('#smscount'); // cache it
$('#Msg').keyup(function() {
  var l = $(this).val().length;
  if(l <= 70) {
    count.text(Math.ceil(l / 70));
  } else {
    count.text(Math.ceil(l / 67));
  }
});
```

Alternatively you might just handle the `.change()` or `.blur()` event to update the value when the textbox loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the javascript function dynamically to get the length of msg like below:

```
       <input type="text" id="Msg" onChange="checkLength();" value=""></input>

       <div id="smscount"></div>
```

and you have to add your javascript code in a function

```
       function checkLength(){

        if (($('#Msg').val().length) <= 70) {

          $('#smscount').text(Math.ceil(($('#Msg').val().length) / 67));
        }
        else 
         {
            $('#smscount').text(Math.ceil(($('#Msg').val().length) / 67));
         }
      }
```

Comment: the textbox has another function in onChange(), many thanks :)